# How to always show overflow menu (ActionBar) even if phone has hardware menu button?

Tags: java, android, xml, menu, android-actionbar

Following mentioned are codes implemented. Please suggest me how to create the "overflow menu" option in action bar even if a phone have the hardware menu button?

This is my current code:

MainActivity.java

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

activity_main_actions.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding ="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- Search  -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<!-- Email -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_email"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_email"
      android:title="@string/action_email"
      android:showAsAction="never"/>

<!-- Help -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_help"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_help"
      android:title="@string/action_help"
      android:showAsAction="never"/>

<!-- attach -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_attach"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_attachment"
      android:title="@string/action_attach"
      android:showAsAction="never" />
```

Comment: Try android:showAsAction="never" for action_search item also..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the answer after all with the following code, it was coded after the method onCreateOptionMenu()...

```
import android.view.ViewConfiguration;

        private void getOverflowMenu(){

         try {
            ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
            Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
            if(menuKeyField != null) {
                menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
                menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Initially, the overflow menu is not shown! It shows if the screen is rotated or menu is pressed. But how can I show it at the app start up?

Comment: Where should I call this method?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

Since you set the showAsAction attribute to never, then these menu items will never show as action views. Try this:

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>

<!-- Email -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_email"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_email"
      android:title="@string/action_email"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>

<!-- Help -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_help"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_help"
      android:title="@string/action_help"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>

<!-- attach -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_attach"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_attachment"
      android:title="@string/action_attach"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
```

Comment: Wrong answer. He don't want to show the action in ActionBar. He want to show the overflow menu even the phone have a menu button. (which isn't the default behavior)