# How to show overflow menu in action bar

Tags: android, android-menu, overflow-menu

I want to display an overflow menu in the action bar , I tried to use a menu in my activity but I'm only getting a popup menu when I click on the **menu button on my phone**. Is there any way **to force that overflow menu** for phone **with physical buttons** ?

Here is my menu file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:title="phone"
        android:icon="@drawable/phone"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item 
        android:id="@+id/computer"
        android:title="computer"
        android:icon="@drawable/computer"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item 
        android:id="@+id/gamepad"
        android:title="gamepad"
        android:icon="@drawable/gamepad"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>


</menu>
```

Comment: Hey these was answered here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22625166

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into the menu xml file and make sure it has

```
 android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

and for the icon you use

```
android:icon="@drawable/yourIcon"
```

Edit: To make sure you are using the right menu xml, check your activity class that is being run and look for the

`onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`

Once you have found that check that the line

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.{0}, menu);
```

matches your menu xml file, where {0} = your xml file name

Comment: This is my menu.xml file in question.it doesn't make any difference.the output is same.I have not created  icon for three dots.I have just use getMenuInFlater().

Comment: If you have showAsAction set, regardless of whether or not you have an icon it should display one of them in text form at least. Have you tried uninstalling the app and re-installing it? Also make sure you added it to the correct menu XML, there will likely be a different menu XML for each activity unless you changed the code to share one common menu xml